# How can I match the first occurrence of '(' in this regex

Tags: python, regex

How can I match the first occurrence of '(' in this regex

The string is:

```
mean(DFBg@t=(391,596))
```

but this pattern: `\(?` will match both opening brackets. How would I get the first.

#### edit: show the code:

```
    >>> import re
    >>> string = 'mean(DFBg@t=(391,596))'
    >>> x = re.findall('\(', string)
    >>> print(x)
    ['(', '(']
```

Comment: You can use `^[^(]*\(`

Comment: Wow that was quick. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the whole relevant code to see what you are doing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew heres a link to the regex on Pythex: https://pythex.org/?regex=%5C(%3F&test_string=mean(DFBg%40t%3D(391%2C596))&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Comment: But that is pointless. You can use `\(` to match the first `(` with `re.search(r'\(', text)`. What are you doing? Show the *code*.

Comment: Do you want to replace the first `(` only? No need for a regex, use `s.replace('(', '-', 1)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes actually, this is perfect. I didn't know about the third argument to replace. Thanks!